# Select the previous row of a certain value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, select, group-by, concatenation

My inventory data contain columns: `sale_date`, `saleID`, `region`, `product`. Each `product` in each `region` can be sold multiple times within that `region`, but each time has a unique `saleID`.

Now, I have a list of `saleID`, I need to select the rows in which the `saleID` is located. Moreover, I need to find the last `saleID` (and the whole row) of this product in this region. In other word, I need to group by `region` and `product` first, and find the `saleID` in the list and find the previous row of this `saleID` in the grouped rows

```
df
sale_date     saleID       region     product     
2017-05-01    A12           Asia       car1
2018-03-05    B21           Asia       car1
2018-04-01    C23           Asia       car1
2018-09-06    C21           Canada     car2
2019-01-01    E11           Canada     car2
2019-03-02    E23           USA        car3
2019-01-02    G41           USA        car3
2015-02-02    H11           Mexico     car4
2015-02-03    I14           Mexico     car4
```

Expected output

```
saleID_list = [B21, E11, I14]
sale_date     saleID       region     product     
2017-05-01    A12           Asia       car1
2018-03-05    B21           Asia       car1
2018-09-06    C21           Canada     car2
2019-01-01    E11           Canada     car2
2015-02-02    H11           Mexico     car4
2015-02-03    I14           Mexico     car4
```

I know we can select the rows with the listed `saleID` using

```
df.loc[df['saleID'].isin(saleID_list)]
```

But can I find the previous row of the groupby data? I attempted to write something like using `shift`, but `AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'loc'`

```
df.groupby(['region', 'product']).loc[df['saleID'].isin(saleID_list)].shift(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) for helper `Series` and test it in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with original mask for test column `saleID` chained by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
saleID_list = ["B21", "E11", "I14"]

s = df.groupby(['region', 'product'])['saleID'].shift(-1)

df = df[df['saleID'].isin(saleID_list) | s.isin(saleID_list)]
print (df)
    sale_date saleID  region product
0  2017-05-01    A12    Asia    car1
1  2018-03-05    B21    Asia    car1
3  2018-09-06    C21  Canada    car2
4  2019-01-01    E11  Canada    car2
7  2015-02-02    H11  Mexico    car4
8  2015-02-03    I14  Mexico    car4
```